# Как выполнить подобный запрос средствами Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Подскажите, как выполнить подобный запрос средствами Eloquent? Под конец дня уже не могу сообразить. А результат необходимо разбить постранично, по этому сырой запрос не подходит.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE ( aux1 IS NOT NULL OR aux2 IS NOT NULL )";
    if( $request->input('own') || $request->input('query') ){
        $query .=
            "AND cases_id IN ( SELECT id FROM cases  WHERE";
        if( $request->input('own')  ){
            $query .= "user_id LIKE '%".  Auth::user()->id ."%' AND ";
        }
        if( $request->input('query') ){
            $query .= "title LIKE '%". $request->input('query') ."%' AND ";
        }
        $query = substr_replace( $query, "", -4 );
        $query .= ")";
    }
    $series = DB::select( DB::raw($query) );
```

Comment: Можно `LIMIT`, можно `array_chunk`.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов разбивать массив пагинацией сделать такую вспомогательную функцию.

```
/**
 * Пагинация для коллекции элементов
 * @param Illuminate\Support\Collection $items
 * @param Request $request
 * @param int $perPage
 * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 */
function paginate($items,$request,$perPage)
{
    $pageStart           = $request->get('page', 1);
    $offSet              = ($pageStart * $perPage) - $perPage;
    $itemsForCurrentPage = $items->slice($offSet, $perPage, TRUE);

    return new Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
        $itemsForCurrentPage, count($items), $perPage,
        Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
        ['path' => Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
    );

}
```